# PHP Get current URL parameter after #

Tags: php, uri

I want to have a variable that contain url address such as this example

when I open http://localhost/test?alfa=b&bravo=c#question=Z

I want to print on my web the "question=Z"

I try to get by using REQUEST_URI

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

The browser just show "/test?alfa=b&bravo=c" without "question=Z"

Could somebody helped me with this issue?
Thanks Before

Comment: two seperate things: "c" is the value of the queried variable bravo transmitted to the server. everything fro the # refers to a local anchor. at least this is how it will be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research on php and java, I can get the #hashtag by combine php n java

here put javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = window.location.hash.replace("#","$");
document.cookie = 'tag=' + test;
</script>
```

And last, put this php to take the variable

```
<?php  
$hashtag = $_COOKIE["tag"]; $hashtag = substr($hashtag,11,1000);
?>
```

I put 1000 because I limit the input question max 1000 character

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just made an error and what you actually mean is:

```
http://localhost/test?alfa=b&bravo=c&question=Z
```

Then your error would just be a typo.

Otherwise, there is no solution to that. Everything including and bafter the # is never actually transmitted to the server. It is evaluated locally on the browser.

The Server only sees the Domain, the URI and teh query string.

Regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

use this kind of URL

```
http://localhost/test?alfa=b&bravo=c&question=Z
```

then in `php` you can catch them by

```
$alfa = $_GET['alfa'];
$bravo = $_GET['bravo'];
$question = $_GET['question'];
```

to catch

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["alfa"] || $_GET["bravo"] )
   {
      echo "I'm ". $_GET['alfa']. "<br />";
      echo "I'm ". $_GET['bravo'];

      exit();
   }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
   if( !empty($alfa) || !empty($bravo) )
   {
      echo "I'm ". $alfa. "<br />";
      echo "I'm ". $bravo;

      exit();
   }
?>
```

---

***About GET***

1. The GET method produces a long string that appears in your server
   logs, in the browser's Location: box.
2. The GET method is restricted to send upto 1024 characters only.
3. Never use GET method if you have password or other sensitive
   information to be sent to the server.
4. GET can't be used to send binary data, like images or word
   documents, to the server.
5. The data sent by GET method can be accessed using QUERY_STRING
   environment variable.
6. The PHP provides `$_GET` associative array to access all the sent
   information using GET method.

---

1. [PHP - GET & POST Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)
2. [HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: It's not error...I certain use the # not & on the last

Comment: you cant use it. use & and get value by `$_GET['question']` this